¿Qué es una gallarda?
La quinta acepción de gallardo, gallarda es:


f. Tañido de la gallarda.


Dado que tañido a su vez es:


m. Acción y efecto de tañer.


y que tañer es tocar un instrumento musical, parece que la gallarda referida en la acepción quinta es algún tipo de instrumento musical.
Sin embargo, ninguna de las restantes acepciones de "gallardo, gallarda" indica ningún instrumento musical, tenemos una definición confusa por incompleta.
¿Alguien sabe qué tipo de instrumento es la gallarda, cuyo tañido es gallarda, según el DLE?

No es un instrumento! Una acción y efecto no es ningún instrumento.

Si te interesa saber más sobre la historia de la gallarda, escuchar la música, ver la danza, hay un video en YouTube que te revela todo esto. La gallarda - Qué es, historia y puesta en escena: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUMyhqcNnJw

La respuesta correcta ya está dada.

Un "vals" es un baile pero también se dice "tocar un vals". Puede que no se refiera a un instrumento concreto sino a la forma musical del renacimiento asociada a esa danza, que fue muy popular incluso tras caer en desuso ese tipo la danza.  Si buscas "gallarda" en youtube encontrarás personas dazando, pero todo de personas "tocando" la gallarda con diferentes instrumentos sin bailar.

@CAT es completamente equiparable, como lo es a prácticamente cualquier género de danza. Acá es lo mismo, cuando se habla de una ‘zamba’ se dice ‘bailar una zamba’ o ‘tocar una zamba’. Con la chacarera, se dice ‘bailar una chacarera’ pero también ‘tocar una chacarera’. Con el tango, se dice ‘bailar tango’ o ‘tocar un tango’. Casi todos los géneros de danza tienen un género musical propio de esa danza. La respuesta de aerobiomat es la correcta.

@CAT es porque son sinónimos. Buscá en Youtube ‘gallarda’ vas a ver que aparecen tipos tocando algo parecido a la música clásica

Aqui lo  tienes:

Danzas del Renacimiento o Cortesanas (Danza gallarda)
Jessica Janette Medrano Gómez.   Introducción
Danzas del renacimiento.
Con la llegada del renacimiento hubo una nueva actitud hacia el
cuerpo, las artes y la danza, el arte comenzaba a florecer. Las cortes
de Italia y Francia se convirtieron en el centro de nuevos desarrollos
en la danza gracias a los apoyos culturales a los maestros de la danza
y a los músicos que crearon grandes danzas dentro de la sociedad que
permitieron la multiplicación de las celebraciones y festividades. Las
danzas de esa época estaban sujetas a muchas reglas en el estilo de
sus pasos y en la evolución de estos mismos, las danzas se dividían en
danzas altas y bajas. Las danzas altas eran las que tenían saltos y
levantamientos de pierna, y las danzas bajas eran las que tenían
desplazamientos, sin separar los pies del suelo al no ser que
prácticamente el paso fuera demasiado sutil y noble. Las reglas eran
muy precisas en cuanto el movimiento del busto, cabeza y brazos ya que
estas eran bailadas en celebraciones y fiestas ocupando un lugar
importante dentro de las cortes por lo tanto todo movimiento debería
de ser perfecto y elegante ya que estos bailes eran muy presentados
dentro de la sociedad media y alta. Algunas de las danzas más famosas
del renacimiento eran: La pavana, la gallarda, la volta, la alemanda,
la corrente, y la gavota.



Danza Gallarda.
Principales características de la danza:
La gallarda fue una forma musical y danza del Renacimiento, popular en
toda Europa en el Siglo XVI. Se la menciona en manuales de danza de
Inglaterra, Francia, España, Alemania e Italia, entre otros. Los
ejemplos más antiguos de esta danza se conservan en la ciudad de
París.
Esta danza se llamó así por que al bailarla uno tenía que estar gozoso
y animado solía interpretarse después de la pavana y era una danza
rápida de compás ternario.
La característica principal de esta danza era una alegría fuerte y
vigorosa al mismo tiempo una buena energía y fuerza en los bailarines.
Esta danza se caracterizaba también de otras que a pesar de que se
bailaba en parejas, cada cual bailaba separados, no siempre la dama
era llevada de la mano cuando se bailaba si no que cada uno de estos
bailaba separados.
Gozo de gran popularidad desde finales del siglo XVI hasta la mitad
del siglo XVII. Según el historiador ingles Parnack, la reina Isabel
hacia ejercicio todas las mañanas bailando de seis a siete gallardas.
Con el reinado de Luis XIII, hombre muy religioso, la volté
desapareció y ya con el rey Luis XIV la gallarda murió totalmente.
Origen de la danza Gallarda:  Provenía de Italia, donde se le conocía
también con el nombre de Romanesca y cuyo nombre deriva de gigolane,
dar puntapiés.

danzap.blogspot
No sé porque no se encuentra el la RAE. La reina hacia su deporte. :)
el tañido de la gallarda puede ser un sonido, cuando se baila. Era por le visto ruidoso.

Es un sonido?? No sería el sonido?

el gallo puede ser un gallo/ el chico puede ser un chico/

La gallarda no es un instrumento, sino una danza.
Su tañido es su música o un aspecto de su música, como su ritmo.
Este es un uso reciente de tañido, relacionado con la danza.

@CAT ese supuesto ‘sonido’ es la música. De qué idioma venís?

Si la cuestión se centra en la coherencia de las definiciones de la RAE, esta puede ser una buena opción: https://x.com/RAEinforma
Doctores tiene la Iglesia...

Otra más OK?
